# pureftp truncates filenames containing whitespace

Tags: ftp, debian, whitespace, pureftpd

I'm running 1.0.28-3+squeeze1 of pure-ftpd on a debian 6.0.6 installation:

```
Running: /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd -l pam -d -u 1000 -O clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log -8 UTF-8 -B
```

The pure ftp configuration (/etc/pure-ftpd/conf):

```
==> AltLog <==
clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log

==> FSCharset <==
UTF-8

==> MinUID <==
1000

==> NoTruncate <==
yes

==> PAMAuthentication <==
yes

==> PureDB <==
/etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb

==> UnixAuthentication <==
no

==> VerboseLog <==
yes
```

I want to be able to transfer files which contain whitespaces in their filename. At the moment I can't transfer such files using Filezilla for example (tried different clients, the same outcome).

This is the server response when trying to upload a file named: **test_import 1.xml**. As you can see below from the logs only **test_import** is considered, the rest is ignored. It might be something related to quotations but I can't figure out what and how to change.

```
==> /var/log/syslog <==
May 21 11:49:08 server01 pure-ftpd: (?@server02.com) [INFO] upload is now logged in
May 21 11:49:08 server01 pure-ftpd: (upload@server02.com) [DEBUG] Command [cwd] [/home/ftp/temp]
May 21 11:49:08 server01 pure-ftpd: (upload@server02.com) [DEBUG] Command [type] [I]
May 21 11:49:08 server01 pure-ftpd: (upload@server02.com) [DEBUG] Command [pasv] []
May 21 11:49:08 server01 pure-ftpd: (upload@server02.com) [DEBUG] Command [stor] [test_import]
May 21 11:49:08 server01 pure-ftpd: (upload@server02.com) [NOTICE] //home/ftp/temp/test_import uploaded  (28 bytes, 76.36KB/sec)

==> /var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log <==
server02.com - upload [21/May/2014:11:49:08 +0200] "PUT /home/ftp/temp/test_import" 200 28
```